# Yaml python parcing for multi values

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

Given test.yml:

```
Step1:
    input: dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null count=8192 bs=8192
    output: 8192+0 records in
    output: 8192+0 records out
```

Plus python script to read it:

```
import yaml

stream = open("test.yml", 'r')
Steps = yaml.load(stream)   
print(Steps)
```

However it returns only the last output:

```
{'Step1': {'output': '8192+0 records out', 'input': 'dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null count=8192 bs=8192'}}
```

How can I get all output values no matter what their number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you want with multiple keys with the same name. YAML associative arrays, like Python dictionaries, must have *unique keys*, and duplicate keys *must* be ignored (perhaps producing a warning) or be treated as an error. See the [YAML specification](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id932806):

> **It is an error for two equal keys to appear in the same mapping node.** In such a case the YAML processor may continue, ignoring the second key: value pair and issuing an appropriate warning.

*Emphasis mine.*

Python dictionaries behave much the same; key-value pairs *must* be unique. The PyYAML parser handles the above case the same way Python dictionaries do; the last entry wins.

A [ticket in the PyYAML tracker](http://pyyaml.org/ticket/128) has asked for there to be a warning or exception in such cases.

Give your steps unique keys, or use lists for the values instead:

```
Step1:
    input: dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null count=8192 bs=8192
    output:
        - 8192+0 records in
        - 8192+0 records out
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! So there is no way to get the values without editing yml file, right?

Comment: @Kedny88: there isn't; your file is malformed and the Python parser did its best to give you at least *some* of the data.